# Unable To establish an oracle connection from c# form Application

Tags: c#, oracle

Im trying to pass two parameters to my oracle package.

I can get the parameters, but it is not being passed into the database.  Every time I run the application it fails to make a connection and goes straight to my `try catch` method.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

This is what I have so far:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;

private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetOrders_OracleCon_GetData(Parameter1,Parameter2);
   // when i output or add in a break i can see that the data does come into the Parameter values. However after that it doesnt go to my db
}

public void GetOrders_OracleCon_GetData(Int32 PM1, String PM2)
{
    using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + dbcon + "; User ID=" + uid + "; Password=" + pass))
    {
        OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();

        objCmd.Connection = objConn;

        objCmd.CommandText = "PCK_Orders.get_data";

        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        objCmd.Parameters.Add("pm1", OracleType.Number).Value = PM1;

        objCmd.Parameters.Add("pm2", OracleType.VarChar).Value =PM2;

        objCmd.Parameters.Add("selected_orders", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {                    
            objConn.Open();

            OracleDataReader objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (objReader.HasRows)
            {                        
                GetOrders_GetData(objReader);
                btnCancel.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Timer_ProgBar.Stop();

                MessageBox.Show("Orders for this Datedoes not exist", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                GP_ClearAllFields("Y", "Y");

                Timer_ProgBar_Initialize(0, "");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Timer_ProgBar.Stop();

            MessageBox.Show("An error has occured");
              // this is the error that i catch but im not sure what is causing it. am i missing something?                  
            Timer_ProgBar_Initialize(0, "");
        }

        objConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error say? Try catching the exception and see what is the error message: `catch (Exception ex)`

Comment: Please use this link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/connection-strings-for-oracle/

Comment: @Alex it says System.InvalidOperationException:Attempt to load oracle client libraries threw badImageFormatException

Comment: Do you have an Oracle Client installed? `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for years, you should not use it for new projects.

Comment: Ah i got it to work,i changed the platform from any CPU to x86